# Is there a tool to migrate Java code using io.swagger 1.5.x annotations to io.swagger 2.x annotations?

Tags: java, swagger, openapi, swagger-2.0

We currently have a java code base with a fair number of REST endpoints that have been annotated with io.swagger 1.5 annotations. We would like to move to OpenAPI 3.0 so I am looking for a tool that will update the annotations in our code to the io.swagger 2.x annotations. Does such a tool exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that I know of. I only know of tools that can migrate swagger yml or swagger json specifications from 1.x versions to 2.x or even from swagger to openApi. [Swagger Converter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-converter) would be one of those.

But migrating Java code with annotations would be a lot of manual work.

Maybe this [guide from David Merrick](https://www.david-merrick.com/2017/11/15/useful-regexes-for-transitioning-swagger-2-0-to-3-0-annotations/) and some find-and-replace with your favorite IDE can spare you some time.

A good future investment could be to refactor all swagger related code into a yaml specification and to generate the javacode from this spec.

This way, you could make a tool based migration of the spec files and generate the Javacode afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion @Erunafailaro. I will give his regex replacements a try. I concur with you that it would be nice to be able to generate the code from documents rather than the other way around. I may try using a converter to migrate a current Swagger doc to OpenAPI then see what CodeGen spits out but to be honest I am pretty skeptical about that process giving a satisfactory result. I would be willing to be proven wrong though!